# cocos2d ccTouchesMoved moving sprite only to top right corner

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, touch, cgrect

Forgive my elementary question as I'm pretty new to cocos2d, but I'm having an issue moving a sprite around.  The method seems to do what I want...as long as it's moving in a positive x and positive y direction (top right corner).  If I try to move it down or left, it doesn't work.

```
-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
    point = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:point]; //create point location
    CCNode *sprite = [self getChildByTag:kTagSprite]; //set sprite
    CGRect spriteRect = CGRectMake(sprite.position.x, sprite.position.y, sprite.contentSize.width, sprite.contentSize.height); //create box around sprite and get position
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(spriteRect, point)){
        [sprite setPosition:point];  //if my pointer is inside of the sprite box, move the sprite
    }
}
```

Thank you.

edit: adding my init and tag reference

```
-(id) init{
    if((self = [super init])){
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
        CCSprite *mySprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"sprite.png"];
        mySprite.position = ccp(240, 40);
        [self addChild:mySprite z:0 tag:kTagSprite];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and i declared the kTagSprite in:

```
enum{
    kTagSprite
};
```

Comment: how did you create the object behind kTagSprite? Show us the code..how do you load the sprite in the init?

Comment: question edited.  thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
    point = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:point]; //create point location
    CCSprite *sprite = [self getChildByTag:kTagSprite]; //set sprite

    if(CGRectContainsPoint([sprite boundingBox], point)){
        [sprite setPosition:point];  //if my pointer is inside of the sprite box, move the sprite      CCLOG(@"THIS WILL BE CALLED");
    }
}
```

run the code and look at the console to see if the log will be called..

Comment: as for the top part of your suggestion, the console only reached that if statement if the object was moving up or right or a mixture of the two.  clicking the object or moving it down and/or left, it did not reach inside the if statement.

however, using your second block of code, everythign worked fine!  thank you very much.  I didn't know about that boundingBox option.